# how to fix the error passing data problem in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

in order to get the weather of a location I've created a LoadingScreen class as shown bellow :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../services/location.dart';
import '../services/networking.dart';
 import './location_screen.dart'; 
  const apiKey = 'd8cdd9eca073d9bbf5ef49405cbf50e8';
  
class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoadingScreen({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
    double? longitude;
    double? lattitude;
   
  @override
  void initState() { 
    // TODO: implement initStat
    super.initState();
     getLocationData();
  }
  void getLocationData() async {
       Location located = Location();
     await  located.getLocation();

     longitude = located.longitude;
     lattitude  = located.lattitude;
     print(longitude);
     print(lattitude);
  NetworkHelper networkhelper = 
 NetworkHelper('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$lattitude&lon=$longitude&appid=$apiKey');
   
   
   var weatherdata =  await networkhelper.getData();
       
/*  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          return  LocationScreen(
            locationWeather: weatherdata,
            );
          },
        ),
        );*/
     Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(LocationScreen.routeName, arguments: weatherdata);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
         body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    );
  }
}
```

with the help of the Network class, I've seperated getdata method as shown in the code bellow :

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';


class NetworkHelper {

    final String url;  
    NetworkHelper(this.url);
  
  Future getData() async{

   var response =   await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
           
         String  data = response.body;
         return jsonDecode(data);

   } else {
     print(response.statusCode);
   }


  }

}
```

when the app opens..it shows a spiner to navigate through the LocationScreen page :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class LocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {

 // var locationWeather;

 //LocationScreen({this.locationWeather});

    static const routeName = '/location-screen';
  @override
  _LocationScreenState createState() => _LocationScreenState();
}

class _LocationScreenState extends State<LocationScreen> {
    double? temperature;
    int? condition;
    String? cityName;
   

    @override 
    void intiState(){

   var weatherData = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as dynamic;
      
    updateUi(weatherData);
     super.initState();
    } 


   void updateUi(dynamic weatherData){
     try {
        temperature = weatherData['main']['temp'];
      condition = weatherData['weather'][0]['id'];
      cityName = weatherData['name'];
      print(temperature);
     } catch (e) {
       print('An error has occured, please try again');
     }
     
   }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image:DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('images/location_background.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
               colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8), BlendMode.dstATop),
            ),
        ),
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: (){}, 
                      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                      size: 50,
                      ),
                      ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: (){},
                       child: Icon(Icons.location_city, 
                       size: 50,
                       ),
                       ),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text('32°', style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Spartan MB',
                        fontSize: 100,
                    ),
                    ),
                    Text('☀️', style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 100.0,
                    ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),    
                 ),
                 Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                 child: Text("It's  time in San Francisco!",
                 textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                  style: TextStyle(
                     fontFamily: 'Spartan MB',
                     fontSize: 60.0,
                  ),
                  ),
                 ),
            ],
          ),
          ),
             ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've passed the weather data using Navigator.of(context).pushNamed method
but when I tried to get the data in order to update the LocationScreen ..I couldn't receive anything (print(temperature) doesn't work) knowing that, when I printed the weather data in the getlocationdata method ..everything worked so that mean there were no problem with my API url ..so where is the problem?

code of the main.dart :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './screens/loading_screen.dart';
import './screens/location_screen.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: LoadingScreen(),
      routes: {
        LocationScreen.routeName: (ctx) => LocationScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo inside the class `_LocationScreenState`. It says `intiState()` when it should be `initState()`.

The IDE should give a warning "The method doesn't override an inherited method" because of the typo.

Also, you can't use `ModalRoute.of(context)` in initState. It wouldn't make sense because initState is supposed to be executed only once, but usually `Something.of(context)` means it might change over time. If you try to use it in initState(), flutter gives an error saying that you should use `didChangeDependencies()` instead. So you should delete your initState() and write this instead:

```
@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  super.didChangeDependencies();
  var weatherData = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as dynamic;
  updateUi(weatherData);
}
```

Also, if you're going to change some state variables, you always have to surround them with `setState(() { ... })`. Otherwise the widget doesn't update on the screen. So add these two lines:

```
void updateUi(dynamic weatherData){
  try {
    setState(() {      //      <--- ADD THIS LINE!
      temperature = weatherData['main']['temp'];
      condition = weatherData['weather'][0]['id'];
      cityName = weatherData['name'];
      print(temperature);
    });                //      <--- ADD THIS LINE!
  } catch (e) {
    print('An error has occured, please try again');
  }
}
```

OR, You could also just make it a StatelessWidget instead of StatefulWidget. Then things would be simpler. You could get rid of updateUi() and you wouldn't need these variables in the class:

```
double? temperature;
int? condition;
String? cityName;
```

Instead you would just query the ModalRoute in the build method like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final weatherData = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as dynamic;
  final double? temperature = weatherData['main']['temp'];
  final int? condition = weatherData['weather'][0]['id'];
  final String? cityName = weatherData['name'];
  print('temperature: $temperature');
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      ...
```

Whether StatefulWidget or StatelessWidget is better, depends on where you want to handle possible run-time changes in the weather display (if you're planning to make the app so that the weather info will change during run-time). If you want to handle the changes inside LocationScreen, then it should be StatefulWidget. Otherwise it should be a StatelessWidget and merely display the data that's coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question.